# Cassandra, filter latest rows from an append only table

Tags: cassandra

Currently I have a simple table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE datatable (timestamp bigint, value bigint,  PRIMARY KEY (timestamp))
```

This table is only growing and never being modified. The key is unique timestamp. All queries are range queries of the form:

```
SELECT * from datatable WHERE timestamp > 123456 ALLOW FILTERING
```

Moreover, queries request only a small set of the latest rows inserted. The problem that I have right now is that performance of these queries negatively correlated with the table size. As table grows, it takes significantly longer to get response, even if query returns just a few rows.

Could you advise on how I should modify table schema to avoid performance degradation (e.g., create index or set clustering)? 
Thanks!

Comment: `ALLOW FILTERING` leads to scanning of all nodes, and it's not recommended - that's why you have performance problems.  Can you add more details on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Pro-tip, if you ever find yourself needing to use `ALLOW FILTERING` in Cassandra, you're *probably* doing it wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add some time bucketing like

```
CREATE TABLE datatable (
  bucket timestamp,
  time timestamp,
  value bigint,
  PRIMARY KEY ((bucket), time)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (time DESC);
```

where bucket is the date truncated to the day or week or month (can figure out how many based on approx ingestion rate, a decent goal is about 64mb per partition but thats very flexible), that way you will collect all the rows for a period within a single partition very efficiently.

Having billions of partitions per node will cause slow down repairs and compactions significantly. Also partitioning order is random (murmur3 hash of the partition key order) so you cannot do things like have your above your query in order.

With the above you can then iterate from the bucket of your start time to the current bucket without `ALLOW FILTERING` (which you should never ever use outside of toy amounts of data or test environment kinda things) and the results will be in the order of the timestamps.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say!

Comment: There are a lot of cassandra-related examples where GUID is used as a primary key. Seems GUID has same perfomance problems as timestamp has. Should kind of `bucket` be also used there to prevent perfomace degragation?

Comment: Small partitions are only really an issue if theres billions though, which happens in time series like above but not usually in entity type things so it isnt always an issue. Outside of timeseries/queue type things this is usually overkill. If you did on a GUID key, you may want to use some kind of artificial key based on guid so you can generate key for a lookup without knowing the date it was added ie mod guid as bigint by 30 million to keep a max constant 30 million keys, or 
 a jumphash/rendezvous hash if want to be able to adjust number of keys.